# "What would you prefer they say?" Grammatical or not?

Tags: word-usage

I know "prefer" can be used this way,

> I would however prefer that you got as much advice as possible from
> the books first.

But when it comes to this one,

> What would you prefer ***(that) they say***?

in which obviously "what" serves as the object of "say", a verb located in a subordinate noun clause.

Tons of examples of this sentence can be found, but is this usage grammatical or standard?

Answer (score 2):

If by saying 'What would you prefer they say?' you mean 'What would you *want them* to say?' then I suppose it is grammatically correct.